# xquery greater then equal function not working

Tags: xquery

i am trying to put a very simple function on XQ and having hard time to get it worked,.

say I am receiving value of $temp_Limit as 6.0 from previous calculation and later just want a comparision where if this value is greater then or equal to 0.0 then display the same value else default 0.0 in response.

```
 (
if ((xs:double($temp_Limit))>= xs:double('0.0'))
then
    $temp_Limit
else
    '0.0'
)
```

Kindly advise whats wrong here.

Comment: I’m not sure what the problem is? What goes wrong?

Comment: Hi @Christian , issue is flow always goes in else block where as it should hit the If block

Comment: This might have to do with your `$temp_Limit` variable; the query you provided is fine. Please rewrite your query such that it can be run without further modifications (e.g. by prefixing it with `let $temp_Limit := '-123' return`).